# Contracting Einstein Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, tensor-calculus

In a book, it is proved that

$$R^k_i-\frac{1}{2}\delta^k_iR=\frac{8\pi k}{c^4}T^k_i \tag{1}$$

Then it says by contacting $i$,$k$,

$$R=-\frac{8\pi k}{c^4}T^i_i \tag{2}$$

How do you prove this? I tried to multiple $(2)$ by $g^i_k$

$$g^i_kR^k_i-\frac{1}{2}g^i_k\delta^k_iR=\frac{8\pi k}{c^4}g^i_kT^k_i \tag{3}$$

$$R-\frac{1}{2}R=\frac{8\pi k}{c^4}T \tag{4}$$

$$R=\frac{16\pi k}{c^4}T \tag{5}$$

What did i do wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that $g^i_k = \delta^i_k$. Your mistake was writing $g^i_k \delta^k_i = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\delta_k{}^k = 4$, and the result follows trivially from the first equation.